# Display score in text widget after button pressed

Tags: java, android

I am making a basic Q & A app. When one answer is ticked, score increments by x. I want the score to be displayed in the bottom text widget "score" when the button is pressed. How can I do this?

My java code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int score = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    question1();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void question1(){
    String Question1 = "Question 1";

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
    TextView A = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerA);
    TextView B = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerB);
    TextView C = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerC);
    TextView D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerD);
    TextView Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);

    t.setText("Question 1");
    A.setText("Answer A");
    B.setText("Answer B");
    C.setText("Answer C");
    D.setText("Answer D");
    Score.setText(score);
}

public int onCheckboxClickedA(){
    return score = score + 1;
}
public int onCheckboxClickedB(){
    return score = score + 2;
}
public int onCheckboxClickedC(){
    return score = score + 3;
}
public int onCheckboxClickedD(){
    return score = score + 4;
    }
}
```

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Question"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Question"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClickedA"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerB"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="osdpoijsd"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClickedB"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerC"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerB"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClickedC"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New CheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerD"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerC"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClickedD"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AnswerD"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/Score"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Which button you want to press and in which conditions score should get reflected on screen.

Comment: Sorry. I want id "button" to be pressed and text field "score" to be altered when pressed. I want score to be altered instantly when button is pressed.

Comment: I added this method to it, but the app crashes when I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

First in method question1()

```
 Score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
```

Second create a reference to button in activity

```
  Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        }
    });
```

Thirdly Create a final object of Score.

```
  final  TextView Score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);
```

Comment: Where do I place the code in main? I keep getting "cannot resolve symbol" error on setOnClickListener and view. 
Image: http://imgur.com/4AteigD

Comment: Place setonclicklistener code inside onCreate method